# Идиома Copy-and-Swap в С++

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов, swap

Уже не в первый раз на моем аккаунте затрагивается Вопрос про задачу о ломаной. На этот раз я хотел бы обсудить "Copy-and-Swap Idiom in C++" в моем коде.
Условие задачи можете прочитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437344/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8), если интересно.

Значит, в своем коде я реализовал идиому Copy-and-Swap:

```
void swap(Loman& a) {
        std::swap(size, a.size);
        std::swap(data, a.data);
    }
 
    Loman& operator=(const Loman& a)
    {
            Loman tmp(a);
            swap(tmp);
        return *this;
    }
```

Но мне кажется в этом коде есть логиеская опечатка и она должна, на самом деле, записываться так:

```
void swap(Loman& first, Loman& second) {
        std::swap(first.size, second.size);
        std::swap(first.data, second.data);
    }
 
    Loman& operator=(const Loman& a)
    {
            Loman tmp(a);
            swap(*this, tmp);
        return *this;
    }
```

Так же мне кажется, что в операторе + есть ненужная операция `this-> size = size`. Если уберу его, то ничего не изменится.

Вот весь код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Loman
{
private:
    int i=0;
    int size;
    int* data;
public:
    Loman(int asize) {
        size = 2*asize;
        data = new int[size];
    }
    ~Loman(){
        delete[] data;
        cout<<"Object destroyed\n";
    }
    Loman(const Loman &ob)
    {
        size = ob.size;
        data = new int [size];
        for(int i=0; i<ob.size; i++)
            data[i] = ob.data[i];
    }
    void print(){
        for(i=0; i<size; i++){
            cout<<*(data+i)<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
 
    void scan(){
        cout<<"Input "<<size/2<<" coordinates\n";
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            cin>>*(data+i);
        }
    }
    Loman operator+(Loman& ob){
        this->size = size;
        Loman tmp((size + ob.size)/2);
        for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            tmp.data[i]=*(data + i);//this->data[i]=data[i];
        }
        for(i=size; i<size + ob.size; i++) tmp.data[i] = ob.data[i-size];
        return tmp;
    }
    void swap(Loman& a) {
        std::swap(size, a.size);
        std::swap(data, a.data);
    }
 
    Loman& operator=(const Loman& a)
    {
            Loman tmp(a);
            swap(tmp);
        return *this;
    }
};
int main(){
    Loman first(3);
    Loman second(2);
    first.scan();
    second.scan();
    Loman third(5);
    third=first+second;
    third.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Вопросы:
Верны ли мои гепотезы про оператор "+", а также про функцию swap, если нет почему?
Упустил ли я еще какие-нибудь ошибки?
Необходимо ли в функции swap написать `using std::swap;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начинаю с конца.

> Необходимо ли в функции swap написать `using std::swap;`

Здесь не обязательно. `using std::swap;`, а затем `swap(x, y);` (уже без `std::`) - это канонический вызов `swap` на произвольном типе.

По умолчанию он вызовет `std::swap`, но если для этого типа есть своя функция `swap` (там, где ее найдет [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) - например, в том же namespace), то будет вызвана она.

Но поскольку здесь вы ее вызываете только на встроенных типах (не на классах), никакого ADL все равно не будет, и смысла заморачиваться нет.

---

Отсюда вытекает ответ про вашу функцию `swap`. Если вы хотите, чтобы ее можно было вызвать таким образом, то она не должна быть нестатическим членом. (Потому что мы делаем `swap(x, y);`, а не `x.swap(y);`.)

То, что вы написали: `void swap(Loman &first, Loman &second)` - это совсем мимо, потому что такая функция принимает три объекта, а не два (третий - `this`, получается `x.swap(y, z)`).

Правильно: `friend void swap(Loman& first, Loman& second) {...}`. Можно было бы подумать, что `static` подойдет, но нет, ADL его не уважает.

---

Еще стоит дописать конструктор перемещения ([`noexcept` не забудьте](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8001823/2752075)). После этого `operator=` лучше переписать так:

```
Loman& operator=(Loman a) noexcept
{
    swap(*this, a);
    return *this;
}
```

Тогда он будет подходить одновременно и для копирования, и для перемещения. Я бы использовал такую форму в любом случае (даже если нет либо копирующего конструктора, либо перемещающего), чтобы не думать.

---

`Loman operator+(Loman& ob)` нужно заменить на `Loman operator+(const Loman &) const`, чтобы `+` мог принимать константные и/или временные объекты.

Аналогично, `void print() const`.

---

В `operator+`, `this->size = size;` ничего не делает. Это одна и та же переменная.

---

Смущает привычка везде писать `*(data+i)`. Чем не угодил `data[i]`?

Еще смущает идея хранить X и Y вперемешку в одном массиве. Лучше сделайте себе `struct Point {int x, y;}` и храните в массиве его. Тогда не нужно будет заморачиваться с умножением размера на два.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, а почему перед функцией swap написали friend?  Она дружественная или что Вы имели ввиду?     И про оператор перемещения, он обязателен, можно юез него?

Comment: @MuradMammadzada *"Она дружественная"* Да. Но еще `friend` помещает функцию наружу класса, и она больше не является (нестатическим) членом класса (т.е. в ней нет `this`, и `x.swap(...)` работать не будет, только `swap(...)`). `struct A {friend void foo(A a) {...}};` - это почти то же самое, что `struct A {friend void foo(A a);}; void foo(A a) {...}` (с единственной разницей, что в первом варианте эту функцию можно вызвать только через ADL, никак иначе).

Comment: @MuradMammadzada *"оператор перемещения, он обязателен, можно юез него?"* Можно, но с ним код обычно работает быстрее. В комментах это не объяснить, гуглите про "перемещение" ("move semantics").

Comment: И в функцию swap почему корректнее поместить 2 объекта?    Потому что работаем с 2-мя?

Comment: @MuradMammadzada Ну да? Вас смутило то, что у вас получилось вызвать вашу исправленную функцию как `swap(*this, tmp);`, но это получилось только потому, что вы находитесь внутри класса (и `this->` подставляется автоматически). Снаружи класса пришлось бы писать `x.swap(x, y)` (вместо `swap(x, y)`). Налицо лишняя передача одного и того же объекта два раза.

Comment: @MuradMammadzada Мне кажется я вас завалил информацией, и вам лучше идти дальше читать книгу, возможно перечитать какие-то предыдущие главы. Начните с разницы между функциями-членами класса и всеми остальными функциями ("свободными" функциями), и между статическими и нестатическими функциями-членами. Еще посмотрите про `const` на функциях - вы его не ставите, значит видимо не совсем понимаете.

Comment: Завалили не то слово, но я очень многое узнал. Благодарю Вас)